# Storing multiple fields of address in entity class

Tags: java, reactjs, angular, typescript, nestjs

I need to store multiple addresses, like `address1` , `address2` and `zipcode` etc.
Should I declare all the fields individually?

for instance:

```
class A{
      // many fields
     Address1:string;
     Address2:string;
     zipCode:number;
     city:String;
   }
```

or is there any better way to declare them in entity class? I have been told creating entity classes is the best practice.

[image]

Comment: Well you can always use a SubType and hence do `class A { addresses: Address[]}`

Comment: Thanks...Can you guide me how to do in typescript?

Comment: You want multiple addresses but only one zipcode?

Comment: @morsor ya Mosor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the addresses are multiple, it seems you have this situation:

```
class A {
  AddressList: string[];
  zipCode: number;
  city: String;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Moros. in database it will contain 2 columns?

Comment: No. Address should be in a separate database table and be referred to using foreign keys

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
class Address {
//...
  zipCode: string;
  city: string; 
// ...
}

class A {
  addresses: Address[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather create a specific class for those fields, something like:

```
class A {
    // many fields
    address: AddressData
}

class AddressData {
    address1: string;
    address2: string;
    zipCode: string;
    city: string;
}
```

IMO it's better to keep data that belong to the same group in a separated class. Also I wouldn't store the two addresses in an array because you would lose the information about the main address and the secondary address.